# How can i monitor memory USAGE of a guest VM in hyper-v (non-dynamic)

Tags: wmi, monitoring, hyper-v

So i want to monitor the actual memory used by a VM.

If dynamic memory is enables, I use the "memory demand" counter.

But what if it isn't? I can get the memory visible to the VM, the memory allocated to the VM, but not the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Without dynamic memory enabled, Hyper-V will allocate exactly as much memory as you have assigned to the VM, whether the VM is actually using it or not.

If you assign 2GB of RAM to a VM, that's how much memory Hyper-V will allocate on the host machine.

To determine the actual amount of memory in use by the VM, you'll probably have to query the OS in the VM directly (via WMI or some other remote management solution).